# In R data frames functions to replace original frame

Tags: r, dataframe

In R, each time a data frame is filtered for example are there any changes made to the source data frame? What are best practices for preserving the original data frame?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: It is possible to modify objects that are passed as arguments, but it is not standard behaviour for functions to do that.  So you should post example code as @user438383 requested if you want a definite answer, but you probably don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I do not understand exactly what you mean but, if you have a .csv file for example ("example.csv") in your working directory and you create an r-object (`example`) from it, the original .csv file is maintained intact.
The `example` object however changes whenever you apply functions or filters to it. The easiest way to maintain an original data frame is to apply those functions to a differently named object (i.e. `example2`)

Answer (score 0):

you may save as another data frame or output them for preservation

```
mtcars1 <- mtcars %>% 
           select(mpg,cyl,hp,vs)
```

Save one object to a file

```
saveRDS(mtcars1 , file = "my_data.rds")
```

Restore the object

```
readRDS(file = "my_data.rds")
```

Save multiple objects

```
save(mtcars, mtcars1, file = "multi_data.RData")
```

Restore multiple objects again

```
load("multi_data.RData")
```